# sql select users that didn't login

Tags: sql

I have a table that saves the urls the customers are entering.When a user logs in it saves in the audit table the url '/auth-engine/login'.
The table also contains timestamp to save the date of the login.

I want to get a query of the users that did not login in a specific period of time.Here's what i tried :

```
select Distinct customer.customer_id ,concat(customer.first_name, ' ', customer.last_name) as name 
from customer 
Where customer.customer_id not in (
select Distinct customer.customer_id 
from customer
inner join audit on customer.customer_id = audit.username
where audit.url = '/auth-engine/login' And audit.server_response_code in ('200' , '201')
And audit.ts_created Between '2016-01-01' And '2016-12-31' )
```

However its not giving me the expected results.
How can i do it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that customer.customer_id = audit.username is correct?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` with a `where...is null`

```
select *
from customer
left join audit
  on customer.customer_id = audit.username
  and audit.url = '/auth-engine/login' 
  And audit.server_response_code in ('200' , '201')
  And audit.ts_created Between '2016-01-01' And '2016-12-31'

where audit.username is null
```